# select option not displaying correctly after .load ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am loading a php page into a spefific div, using this code

```
function peopleEdit(id, currid) {


       $("#people_edit").load( "people_edit.php?id="+currid );


return false;
}
```

There are 2 issues though.

1. the form displayed, has the option values out of the select box, and the option is not working.
2. the tinymce box is displayed but the data are out of the box.

the form is tested and is working properly before the ajax .load

here's the html of the form.

```
<form action="people.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="pelatesForm" id="pelatesForm" method="post">

    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">

          <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Τύπος</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <select name="pelates_type_det" id="pelates_type_det" />
          <option value="<?php echo $pelates_det_type ?>"><?php echo $pelates_det_type ?></option>
          <option value="Πελάτης">Πελάτης</option>
          <option value="Προμηθευτής">Προμηθευτής</option>
          </select>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
              <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Όνομα</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_first_name_det" type="text" id="pelates_first_name_det" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_first_name ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
                    <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Επίθετο</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_last_name" type="text" id="pelates_last_name" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_last_name ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>

          <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Τηλέφωνο - Σταθερό</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_phone" type="text" id="pelates_phone" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_phone ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
                <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Τηλέφωνο - Κινητό</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_cell" type="text" id="pelates_cell" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_cell ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>

                      <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Email</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_email" type="text" id="pelates_email" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_email ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
                            <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Όνομα εταιρείας - Ιδιώτης</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>  
        <input name="pelates_company" id="pelates_company" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_company ?>" />
        </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
                                  <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">ΑΦΜ</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_afm" type="text" id="pelates_afm" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_afm ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">ΔΟΥ</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_doy" type="text" id="pelates_doy" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_doy ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
                            <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Διεύθυνση</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_address" type="text" id="pelates_address" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_address ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
                            <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Ταχυδρομικός κώδικας</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_tk" type="text" id="pelates_tk" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_tk ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
                                  <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Περιοχή</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="pelates_area" type="text" id="pelates_area" size="64" value="<?php echo $pelates_det_area ?>" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Σχόλια</td>
        <td width="80%">
          <textarea name="pelates_comments_det" type="text" class="tinymce" id="pelates_comments_det" size="64" /><?php echo $pelates_det_comments ?></textarea>
        </td>
      </tr>

          <tr>

        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
        <input name="thisID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $targetID ?>" />
          <input type="submit" name="submitpel" id="submitpel" value="Υποβολή" /> 
          <input type="button" value="Άκυρο"  onclick="return epistrofi('people_detailed','<?php echo $targetID ?>');" />
        </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

any ideas of why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You close your `select` :

```
<select name="pelates_type_det" id="pelates_type_det" />
```

Change to:

```
<select name="pelates_type_det" id="pelates_type_det">
```